# MySQL count() within subquery

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count the number of bookings for the next 7 days with the following query.

```
select calendarDate, 
   (
    select COUNT(*)
    FROM isBooked INNER JOIN booking
    ON isbooked.BookingID = booking.bookingID
    where specificday between booking.startDate and booking.endDate
    ) 
from calendar as specificday
where calendardate between  '2015-08-23' and DATE_ADD('2015-08-23', INTERVAL 6 DAY);
```

I have used SQL server which allows the use of 'as specificday' however MySQL does not, how would i rewrite the query in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`specificday` refers to a table, not a column.  You need a column name for the `WHERE` clause:

```
select c.calendarDate, 
       (select COUNT(*)
        from isBooked ib INNER JOIN
             booking b
             ON ib.BookingID = b.bookingID
        where c.calendarDate between b.startDate and b.endDate
       ) 
from calendar c
where c.calendardate between '2015-08-23' and DATE_ADD('2015-08-23', INTERVAL 6 DAY);
```